# How to disable custom error page generation in IIS server

Tags: spring, apache, iis, spring-boot, webserver

My `Spring Boot` application running on `IIS Server` generating custom error page for remote request finding error code `401` at header. I want to disable it. There should be no custom error page in response data. Desired behavior is there as default in `Apache server`. Though `IIS Server` can be configured to prevent generating custom error page for remote request, I want it to be configured from my application (Web Configuration point may be). Is it possible in `Spring`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a `web.config` file to your app's webapp directory `(app/src/main/webapp)`. `web.config` file should consist:

```
<configuration>
   <system.webServer>
      <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" existingResponse="Auto" />
   </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

this will cause `IIS web server` to set error mode to `'Detailed'` which will prevent generating custom error page.

Answer (score 0):

In your web.xml add this:

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>401</error-code>
    <location>/errors/unauthorised</location>
</error-page>
```

Then add a controller like this:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/errors")
public class ApplicationExceptionHandler {

    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED)
    @RequestMapping("unauthorised")
    public ModelAndView unauthorizedError(){
        return new ModelAndView("errors/error.jsp");
    }
}
```

Comment: actually I was looking for a way to configure web server from application. thanks, I could figure out.